# Firebase: Listening for like changes of a Tree

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Lets say I have a query of a list of Objects

```
-Tree
  -obj1
    -msg: Hi
    -comments: 2
  -obj2
    -msg: Hey
    -comments: 3
```

Lets say I initially pull down obj1 and obj2. And later on I query again, and obj1 and obj2 both have a different comment count

Is there a way to only pull down the data changes rather than the entire object? This is a minimal example but I would likely have more information in it as well.

Or is this motivation to build everything in trees as flat as possible to minimize data transfer?

I noticed in Cloud Firestore you could query just for changes, but it is in beta so I am trying to avoid using it

Any ideas? Basically I am asking how to query for changes from my last query

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database always reads and exposes complete nodes to your listeners.

That means that in your example you can listen for `/Tree/obj1/comments` to get only notified if the comment count for `obj1` changes. But you cannot listen for updates to the comment counts across all objects with a single listener.

If you only want to read comment counts across all objects, you should indeed store a list of comment counts.